# host name retrieval using parse_url function

Tags: php

I need to retrieve 'host' against a list of urls saved in a text file. The following code processes 1 url at a time.

```
 $bits = parse_url("http://me:secret@example.com/cgi-bin/board?user=fred");
 echo $bits['host'];
```

want to extract

```
                example1.com
                example2.com
                example2.com
```

Comment: what you want to do ?/

Comment: file() creates an array, just loop that

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
foreach(file('your_file') as $h){

 $bits = parse_url($h);
 echo $bits['host']; 
}
```